# Media queries not working in Firefox v10

Tags: firefox, css, media-queries

I have been using media queries in my main style sheet to load different styles based on the screen size.

Everything was working fine until I upgraded to Firefox v 10.0.  Now the media queries aren't being pulled in and it appears firefox is ignoring some of the widths that are defined as a percentage.

Here's an example of the media query I'm using:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
body { background: #ddd; }
}
```

I have always been able to test by shrinking my browser window.  Chrome, Safari, and Opera all work as expected. 
IE ignores it as usual although is working better with the widths than firefox.

Is anyone else having this issue with firefox?

Comment: It still seems to work with pages such as this one: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/mediaqueries.html. Do you have the actual page for us to test with?

Comment: Yes.  you can use https://socialmarketingandtraining.com If you fire up this site in chrome and firefox you'll see that chrome shrinks.. when it gets to a certain point it drops the sidebar below the content area and hides the feature area.  This was working in firefox 9.

Comment: NOTE: this themes sets a cookie for first time visitors to display a different Feature.. you'll need to refresh to see the feature area I'm talking about.  Thanks for the effort

Comment: Looks the same in Firefox and Chrome for me.  Chrome did give me a warning about the `https` page containing insecure content.  Are any of your stylesheets getting served on `http`?

Comment: What version of firefox are you using?  Did the sidebar move below the content in firefox.. I'm not sure how to fix the https warning in chrome..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you see the issue in safe mode?

I'm guessing you have some extension installed which got reenabled with Firefox 10 (which treats extensions as compatible by default) and this extension prevents your actual browser viewport from shrinking with the browser window.  When this happens, for example, you should see the vertical scrollbar on the right disappear from the viewport.  Do you see that happening?

Comment: I disabled all my extensions and then re-enabled them 1 by 1.  The culprit was Google Shortcuts 2.1.7.1

Thanks SO MUCH!

Comment: I will add Wappalyzer and Flagfox to the list, they seem to break the smaller @media queries.

Answer (score -1):

I was testing the Firebreak add-on for Firefox, it broke responsive queries at small size (< 524px). I disabled it and the queries are working again.